# Copying Android source code directory from one computer to an other one

Tags: android, git

I have downloaded the Android source code on my computer using the repo sync command. Since I have no experience with git and repo , I would like to know if it is possible to copy the mydroid directory (which contains Android source code) to an other computer by just burning it on a DVD and then processing the build without problems.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my question is stupid

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you have to do is to copy the directory containing `.git` directory. You can test it out by copying it locally and then going into that copied directory and perform a few git commands (like `git log`).

Comment: Yep. If the build works in the first copy that you cloned from the Android repo, it should work for any copies of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, copying the root Android directory will work fine.